# User keyword's robot.running.model.Keyword object children attribute returns empty list in prerunmodifier start_suite function

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a simple prerunmodifier that implements the `start_suite` function in which it gets the suite setup keyword from the `suite` variable and prints its attributes. The object is an instance of `robot.running.model.Keyword` class, here is the [doc](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.running.html?highlight=robot.running.model.Keyword#robot.running.model.Keyword) for that class. The `name`, keyword `type`, `id` and `parent` attributes are correct but the `timeout`, `doc`, `tags`, `children` attributes return nothing. It is the same with `keywords` and `messages` attributes. Below is my simplified code example and the output.

I would expect the following children: Log, Log Many, No Operation. Is it possible to get the name (and arguments) of these keywords in a prerunmodifier like this? I am using robotframework==3.1.2.

This is the suite file (test.robot):

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup    Custom Suite Setup Keyword

*** Test Cases ***
A test
    No Operation
    
*** Keywords ***
Custom Suite Setup Keyword
    [Timeout]    2 min
    [Documentation]    It is a keyword doc.
    [Tags]    1TAG    2TAG
    Log    1st child
    Log Many    2nd    child
    No Operation
    [Teardown]    My Keyword Teardown
    
My Keyword Teardown
    Log     teardown
```

This is the prerunmodifier (modifier.py):

```
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class MyModifier(SuiteVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        self._BuiltIn = BuiltIn()
        
    
    def start_suite(self, suite):
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'suite keywords - {suite.keywords}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'class          - {type(suite.keywords.setup)}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'name           - {suite.keywords.setup.name}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'id             - {suite.keywords.setup.id}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'parent(suite)  - {suite.keywords.setup.parent}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'timeout        - {suite.keywords.setup.timeout}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'type           - {suite.keywords.setup.type}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'doc            - {suite.keywords.setup.doc}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'tags           - {suite.keywords.setup.tags}')
        self._BuiltIn.log_to_console(f'children       - {suite.keywords.setup.children}')
```

This is the output:

```
prompt# robot --prerunmodifier modifier.MyModifier --pythonpath ./ test.robot
suite keywords - [Custom Suite Setup Keyword]
class          - <class 'robot.running.model.Keyword'>
name           - Custom Suite Setup Keyword
id             - s1-k1
parent(suite)  - Test
timeout        - None
type           - setup
doc            -
tags           - []
children       - []
==============================================================================
Test
==============================================================================
A test                                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test                                                                  | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Robot Framework 4.0 it is possible if the keyword that is used as a suite setup is implemented within the suite itself, aka if the suite owns the keyword. The [`robot.running.model.TestSuite`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestSuite) [`resource`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestSuite.resource) attribute's doc says:

> [`ResourceFile`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.ResourceFile) instance containing imports, variables and keywords the suite owns. When data is parsed from the file system, this data comes from the same test case file that creates the suite.

So the children keywords and their args can be found in `suite.resource.keywords` object list.

```py
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor

class Visitor(SuiteVisitor):
    
    def start_suite(self, suite):
        for keyword in suite.resource.keywords:
            if suite.setup.name == keyword.name:
                for item in keyword.body:
                    print(f'{item.name} - {item.args} - {item.type}')

                if keyword.teardown.name:
                    print(f'{keyword.teardown.name} - {keyword.teardown.args} - {keyword.teardown.type}')
```

This prints:

```
Log - ('1st child',) - KEYWORD
Log Many - ('2nd', 'child') - KEYWORD
No Operation - () - KEYWORD
My Keyword Teardown - () - TEARDOWN
```

Again, this does not work if the user keyword is implemented in an imported resource file and not in the suite file itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to find the relevant part in Robot Framework's [API documentation](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/master/autodoc/robot.model.html#module-robot.model.visitor). What I am trying to achieve is not possible.

> Visitors make it easy to modify test suite structures or to collect
> information from them. They work both with the `executable model` and
> the `result model`, but the objects passed to the visitor methods are
> slightly different depending on the model they are used with. **The main**
> **differences are that on the execution side keywords do not have child**
> **keywords nor messages**, and that only the result objects have status
> related attributes like `status` and `starttime`.