# Wrapping a test case in Robot Framework in keyword based on the tag of a test

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot Framework supports two ways to interact with the tests and modify the test structure:

- the visitor internal API
- the listener API

I would like to prepend, to specific tests, a given keyword, or even more precisely to wrap the test in a given keyword, if that test has a specific tag. Which of the two approaches should I choose, and how I should use the API of the Body of Robot Framework to wrap it in a `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a prerunmodifier you can modify the suite **before** execution, with a listener you can modify the suite **during** execution. As you have all the information available before execution it is suggested to use a prerunmodifier and do every modifications beforehand.

What needs to be done is creating a user keyword with the same body as the test case that needs to be wrapped. These are the steps:

1. Check `test.tags` for your specific tags.
2. Create a [`robot.running.model.UserKeyword`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.UserKeyword) object for the test case.
3. Copy `test.body` to `ukw.body` effectively replicating the test case as a keyword.
4. Append the new keyword to the keywords available in the suite's resource ([`suite.resource.keywords`](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/autodoc/robot.running.html#robot.running.model.TestSuite.resource)). Make sure the keyword name is unique for every test case. (This entire step is that was the missing link in the previous version of the answer.)
5. Clear the original `test.body`.
6. Add the `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` that would call the newly made user keyword to `test.body`.

This will handle `IF/ELSE IF/ELSE` and `FOR` blocks or their combinations in nested structures.

`start_suite` visitor function should be implemented because access is needed to the `suite.resource.keywords` object.

Visitor.py:

```py
from robot.api import SuiteVisitor
from robot.running.model import UserKeyword

class Visitor(SuiteVisitor):

    def start_suite(self, suite):
        for test in suite.tests:
            if 'WRAP' in test.tags:                                     # step 1.
                keyword_name = f'Wrapper Keyword For Test:{test.name}'

                ukw = UserKeyword(name=keyword_name)                    # step 2.
                ukw.body = test.body                                    # step 3.
                
                suite.resource.keywords.append(ukw)                     # step 4.
            
                test.body.clear()                                       # step 5.
                test.body.create_keyword(                               # step 6.
                    name='Wait Until Keyword Succeeds',
                    args=['10 sec', '2 sec', keyword_name])
```

Example test and results:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test A
    [Tags]    WRAP
    KW
    Log        step 1
    Log Many    step 2    step 3
    IF    True
        Log    true
    END
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    10
        FOR    ${j}    IN RANGE    10
            Log Many    ${i}    ${j}
        END
    END

Test B
    [Tags]    SMOKE
    Log    1
    Log    1


*** Keywords ***
KW
    Log    1
    Log    2
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful, almost there. How did you find all these informations about robofraemwork api?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 I read this a lot: https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ and I had my struggles as well: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63491306/3820025. Defining user keyword is something I have not done yet but I have some other ideas only those needs some time to be evaluated.

Comment: Actually I could use the same in case of my problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66943191/3820025.

Comment: glad you helped yourself solving your problem by helping myself solving my problem

Comment: How did you pass the modifier to the cli? I get the error module 'my_modifier' has no attribute 'visit_suite', which I imagine means I also need to pass the class name somehow to robotframework?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 If the file and the class share the same name: `--prerunmodifier Visitor.py` if the class has a different name than the file then `--prerunmodifier filename.classname`, in this case you might have to set the PYTHONPATH for that you could use the `--pythonpath path/to/file` or edit your ENV variable.

Comment: Now it works, except that it fails because I am on robot 3.2.2 and the test has no body keyword, just "keywords" I think

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Yes, my answer works starting from 4.0 where there has been changes that are documented here: [Running and result models have been changed](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/rf-4.0.rst#running-and-result-models-have-been-changed).

Answer (score 1):

I think the Listener API might be the way to go but why not use the Test and Suite Setup Keywords to be able to pull off what you are trying to do. However, in general, i.e. not just in Python or Robot Framework, it is a bad idea to have one test depend on the execution of another test. Ideally, each test should be able to run on its own, whether first or last or anywhere in the sequence so perhaps there might be a need to refactor your tests and/or Keywords to be able to achieve what you are attempting.

Comment: I am thinking my question wasn't very clear. Here I would not have any test depending on other tests, just tests with a given tag being "instrumented" and my bigger problem is I do not know how to use roboframework API to achieve this instrumentation

Comment: well the listener has a start_test which can accept the test data and the body, so I want to write something such as: "if 'my-tag' is in test.body: test.body = wrap(test.body). Or should I use a prerunmodifier?